# How to change main activity in Android programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Is it possible to create two entry points to an application in Android, I mean can I switch the main activity programmatically?

Comment: Is this different from having an entry point that just decides to do one of two possible things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this one below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName,mainActivity));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
ctx.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

*Every exported activity* is a potential entry point into your app; a foreign app can start any of them with an intent.  (An intent-filter comes with an implicit android:export.) You can however only have one entry point that the launcher will respect.  To simulate a second launch-point, either

1. Provide a completely separate app with the purpose of starting one of your exported activities, or
2. Give your 'launch' activity the sole purpose of immediately starting one or another activity based on some logic (a saved preference, a phase-of-moon calculation, anything).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about launching activity decision based on some events, then you need to add a broadcast receiver, like by clicking on app icon on launcher if you want to start Activity1. then add intent filters to this activity Action_MAIN and ACTION_LAUNCHER, if you want to start Activity2 on phone boot up, then add filter to this activity, BOOT_COMPLETED.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about to launch other apps from your apps then this can be the code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName,mainActivity));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
ctx.startActivity(intent);
```